# "can't access lexical declaration 'players' before initialization"

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, es6-modules, circular-dependency

i am using modules in my javascript project.
i searched the net for this problem, but could not find a solution to this problem in the context of modules.

here's my code:

(main.js):

```
         "use strict";
         export let players = 1;
         import { string1 } from "./cube.js";
```

(cube.js):

```
         "use strict";
         import { players } from "./main.js";
         export let string1 = "text 1234";
         console.log(players);   // error: can't access lexical declaration 'players' before initialization
```

i thought since variable "players" is imported from "main.js" it should be accessible. i am probably blind to a little obvious thing but don't know what?

can someone point me to the answer or solution to this problem please, thanks!!

Comment: Btw, remove those `"use strict";` prologues. All module code is strict anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You have circular imports here. You import `cube.js` from `main.js` and vice versa.
So cube.js can't import `players` because `main.js` already imported `cube.js`.
You can check documentation https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_cycles

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `import { string1 } from "./cube.js";` in *main.js*. With that, you have a circular import, and when starting to load *main.js*, it will force *cube.js* to be evaluated before *main.js* has run and initialised the variable `players` - it's still in the temporal dead zone. If you would access it later, it would work.